# Using regex, match, parallel assignment: Each word to a variable. Meta-programming?

Tags: ruby, regex, metaprogramming

I have an array of four word sentences like: `example = "a four word sentence"` I want to `match` each word `\w+` to a variable as `a,b,c,d`.

```
a,b,c,d = example.match(/(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)/)[1..4]
 #=> ["a", "four", "word", "sentence"]
```

**I would like to get an idea of how this can be done elegantly using a `regex`**?

A simple alternative I thought of is:

```
a,b,c,d = example.split
 #=> ["a", "four", "word", "sentence"]
```

What if I have a sentence with 5 words? Say `five_word_example = "this sentence has five words"` I want the variable `e` to dynamically insert itself at `_` *Perhaps this is called meta-programming?*

```
num = five_word_example.split.count
 # generate `num` of variables here: a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d,_ = five_word_example.split
 #=> ["this", "sentence", "has", "five", "words"]
```

*Pseudo code example:*

```
five_word_example.split.each do |word|
  ('a'..'z').each do |var|
    var = word
  end
end
```

Now assume I call `a` I expect back `#=> "this"`

**Questions Summary**

1. How can match words to var using a simple powerful `regex`?
2. How can I dynamically generate a variable based on the number of words in a sentence?

Comment: @devnull Yes but how do you dynamically assign variables to elements of the array?

Comment: What is the point here?  Can't you access an array element?

Comment: @dev I updated the question. Just experimenting with code. I'd like to assign the variable/value dynamically. Not sure if this has any value/point/ or purpose. Just would like to know if it can be done. And first part of question is asking for a cleaner, more refined regex.

Comment: Yes, you could probably do it. It's also almost certainly not a good idea, as it violates separation of behavior and data (which, in my opinion, is one of the more important features of object oriented programming). There's not really much you can do with the variables once you've created them, because you don't know how many you're going to have in the first place.

Comment: I also don't want to totally discourage you from exploring this, because experimenting is good both for your development as a programmer and for generating new ideas in general, so I'll say this: see what you can accomplish with instance variables.

Comment: You could probably do it with eval

Comment: A couple of small points: if `a, b = "cat and hat".split`, `a => "cat"` and `b => "and"`.  If `a, _, c = "cat and hat".split`, `a
=> "cat"` and `c => "hat"`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will prefer using scan to find all matches of a regex in a string.

```
1.9.3p448 :040 > sentence = "a four word Sentence"
 => "a four word Sentence"
1.9.3p448 :041 > sentence.scan(/\w+/)
 => ["a", "four", "word", "Sentence"]
1.9.3p448 :042 > sentence.scan(/\w+/) {|x| puts "Word: " + x}
Word: a
Word: four
Word: word
Word: Sentence
 => "a four word Sentence"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

```
example = "a four word sentence"
words_array = example.split
words_array.count.times do |a|
 instance_variable_set("@#{('a'..'z').to_a[a]}",words_array[a])
end

irb(main):092:0> @a
=> "a"
irb(main):093:0> @b
=> "four"
irb(main):094:0> @c
=> "word"
irb(main):095:0> @d
=> "sentence"
irb(main):096:0> @e
=> nil
```

Comment: I was about to put up something similar, but expressed a little differently: `"cat and hat".split.each_with_object(96.chr) {|w,var| instance_variable_set("@#{var.succ!}", w)}`.  Then 
`@a #=> "cat"`, `@b #=> "and"` and `@c #=> "hat"`.  Somehow this seems of pretty limited utility.